# dd-wrt: change LAN port to WAN only works without LAN connection

Tags: router, routing, dd-wrt

I have a TP-Link 740N v3 router with WAN port and LAN port 1 burned.

I was able to flash DD-WRT and to apparently configure WAN port to LAN 
port 4 (or 1, I don't actually know how are they numbered by kernel).

Laptop on Wi-fi receives a correct address, from 192.168.1.* network.

But PC, on a wire, receives an IP address from 37.* (for example) network. After that, routing from Internet to Wi-fi 192.168.1.* network stops. 
When PC is off, Internet appears on 192.168.1.* again. Apparently, PC grabs an external IP and "all the Internel" from WAN.

**Is there anything except `vlan1ports`/`vlan0ports` I should configure?**

Some diagnostics, ipconfig and so: https://gist.github.com/92899e26d2e35897714c

What else do I need to change to get port 4 to be WAN and wired ports 2-3 to be LAN (onto 192.168.1.* network)?

**edit:**

Apparently I need to [add another VLAN for local Ethernet ports](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Bridging_WAN_and_a_LAN_port#Separate_LAN_ports_.28into_another_subnet.29), other then the "new WAN" (port #4). That's because PC gets an IP over Ethernet directly from WAN, and I need PC to be on LAN (192.*) network.

But my router doesn't have a [VLAN admin GUI](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Detached_Networks_%28Separate_Networks_With_Internet%29#Procedure), though it's of the same version - `v24 preSP2`.

I followed all the [instructions to separate Ethernet ports into different VLANs](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Bridging_WAN_and_a_LAN_port#Separate_LAN_ports_.28into_another_subnet.29), and still no luck, PC still grabs an IP from my ISP as if the router was a simple switch.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Switched_Ports#vlan.23ports) for how to understand port numbers. The entire article has step-by-step procedure of replacing the uplink port.

Comment: I did follow it, as you can see from `nvram show` output. Something still went wrong. Do you know what it was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't configured the LAN ports correctly yet. The ports are still acting like a hub and not like a firewall; hence the PC grabbing the external IP. As far as I know the areas to look into are VLAN(which you're already doing) and global router settings(like if it's a bridge, gateway or router).

Have you tried again with the latest firmware?

Comment: I cannot try the latest firmware - I don't have that router any longer. I believe you're correct about the gateway/router setting.